# google.script.run problem on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a Google Apps Script project, and I have made a html form that will automatically paste the user answers in a sheet.

My problem is the following: I need to add elements in a drop down list with a separated form. To do this, I have made a function that will read some cells and add their value in a "list". I joined that list to return a string named `listVlans`.

This is my GS:

```
function returnList() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let VLANS = ss.getSheetByName("VLANS");
  let list = VLANS.getRange(3, 9, VLANS.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues();
  let listVlans = list.join();
  return listVlans;
}
```

There is no problem here, it returns a big string (`listVlans`) with all the elements of my list separated by `,`.

My problem is that I would like to import this `listVlans` from the `.gs` to my html script to actualize my drop down list elements in function of my sheet's values.

```
<script>
    function getList()
    {
      let newList = google.script.run.returnList();
      console.log(newList);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the `console.log(newList)` is just printing `undefined`,  but it should print my big joined string...

Have you had this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Thibaud, the problem is not here, you have to evaluate your form by a script included in gs like this one (change names as necessary, inside this script)

```
function lister() {
  const html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('formList')
    .evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Lister ...');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have an other function that makes the link between the .gs and the html : 

function form()
{
  let form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Formulaire');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form, "Gestion Adressage LCI");
}

Is this better to use .createTemplateFromFile() ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but you have to use createTemplateFromFile to transfer the data and evaluate (in my experience https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xjHoIMMPOU0movaHd9q0di3RAQ1uLQsn7S3qHM3SDQY/copy )

Comment: There is something that i don't understand in your code. How can you call "contact" and the function "recupererContatc()" from gs to the html ? What is the function of "<? ... ?> ? Is it Php ? in my code, a function defined in the gs is totally ignored by html script
PS: i can't share the Sheet, it is protected by my society

Comment: Je vais expliquer en Français le problème qui me bloque dans mon projet :
-Je veux un formulaire pour rajouter des nouveaux VLANs 
-Je veux que ce VLAN se rajoute automatiquement dans une liste déroulante d'un autre formulaire.
-Problème : je n'arrive pas à transférer une liste du gs vers le script HTML.

Auriez vous des morceaux de codes simples qui permettraient de juste récupérer une variable du gs vers le html ?
Impossible avec google.script.run.maFonction(), maFonction retourne ma liste dans le gs mais pas dans le HTML.
J'éspere avoir été clair, n'hésitez pas à me contredire.

Comment: Here is a minimal, reproducible example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bx6OyW5WiICzqFOAFjBhf0S3ureZMmpZEQdrEJQgjtg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mike, i will study this, and give you a feed back if I success !

Comment: si on parle français ici on risque de se faire exclure ... il existe un site français sheets pratique

Comment: Mike you just solved my problem, your exemple is totally perfect, thank you so much